# css div and float positioning error

Tags: html, css

I have a layout which consists of menu on left and main content in the next div. What is happening however, is that the content div doesn't appear to be positioning correctly. It is halfway down the menu instead of correctly aligned at the top. As a novice to css I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Please excuse the inline style, but this is just for learning. I posted original code at fiddle but when I submitted my question, message stated to supply inline code. Thanks

UPDATE: Added Image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#menu" ).menu();
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#menuevents" ).menu();
    });
    </script>



<ul id="menuevents" style="width:20%;margin-top:5px;float:left;height:auto !important;">
          <div style="padding:255px 0 5px 3px;color:blue;float:left;clear:both;"></div>

        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Junk Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deleted Items</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Delphi</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Salzburg</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Perch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Amesville</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul id="menu" style="width:20%;margin-top:15px;float:left;clear:both;height:auto !important;">


        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Junk Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deleted Items</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Delphi</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Salzburg</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Perch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Amesville</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div style="padding-left:1%;float:left;clear:inherit;">&nbsp;</div>

        <div id="main" style="width:25%;border-left:thin solid #cccccc;border-right:thin solid #cccccc;padding:0 0 0 2%;height:500px;float:left;overflow:auto;">
          <br />

          <table id="customers">
            <form <form name="search" action="" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="text" id="mailsearch" name="mailsearch" value="Search" size="40" maxlength="40"  min="" max="" accept=""/>

            </form>
            <br /><br />

    </table>  

        </div>
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/jHRgc/7/

Comment: So are you saying the box on the right scrolls down the page when other content is added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `float` from your `#main` div. The menus alone could float, living the content to position itself accordingly.

Comment: I have removed the float and it is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get things to float properly by removing the unnecessary floats on the #main, and adding a nav wrapper for both of your menus. Try this CSS:

```
#main{
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    padding: 10px;
}
nav{
    float: left;
}
#menuevents, #menu{
    margin:5px 10px 0 0;
}
#menu{
    margin-top:15px;
}​
```

Change your HTML to this:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="menuevents">    
    <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Junk Email</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Deleted Items</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Delphi</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Salzburg</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Perch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Amesville</a></li>

  </ul>

  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Junk Email</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Deleted Items</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Delphi</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Salzburg</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Delphi</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Perch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Amesville</a></li>    
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="main" style="">
    <form <form name="search" action="" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input type="text" id="mailsearch" name="mailsearch" value="Search" size="40" maxlength="40"  min="" max="" accept=""/>
    </form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YPXqd/6/

NOTE: You should NEVER use inline styles unless you absolutely have to.
NOTE #2: You should avoid using `!important` at all costs.